# How to use a controller outside of ngApp's scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Due to the structure of an existing project I'm working on, I'm stuck with a template that looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="example">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" id="inner">
    {{ inside }}
  </div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" id="outer">
  {{ outside }}
</div>
```

`#outer` is supposed to be using the same controller as `#inner`, but as it's located outside of `ngApp`'s scope, `{{ outside }}` will not be evaluated. Unfortunately I can't change the template structure, so I tried to compile `#outer`'s content like this:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $compile){
  $rootScope.$apply($compile(document.getElementById('outer'))($rootScope));
});
```

This works, but the controller function will be executed twice, which is not desired. Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

[Working example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T5mEBBE3PqFcqwCFA1Sl?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

what you could do instead, is NOT define ng-app at all in the html, and instead bootstrap angular via javascript.
for example you can do angular.bootstrap(document, ['example']); where 'example' is the angular module for the app for example angular.module('example', [
        'ngResource', 'ui.router', ....
    ]);
you probably defined that yourself already.
This way, you define the ng-app on the entire document scope.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but with your solution the controller function is still executed twice.

Comment: because you put the controller twice. each time you put a controller, its a new instance. thats how angular works.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal, you're initializing twice the controller. You could simply create another div, wrapping all the divs you want and use alias. But this will still initialize twice, but each div will have different values, like, {{inside}} on first div will not have the same as the second one has.

```
   <div ng-app="example">
    <div>
     <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as FirstCtrl" id="inner"> // alias FirstCtrl
     {{ inside }}
     </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as SecondCtrl" id="outer"> // alias SecondCtrl
     {{ outside }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

But if you intend to use just once the same controller, as far as I'm concerned, you'll have to wrap all divs you want to use the same controller, in just one div, like:

```
 <div ng-app="example" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="inner">
    {{inside}}
  </div>
  <div id="outer">
   {{outside}}
  </div>
 </div>
```

This will initialize just once.
Other way, could be attaching **ng-app** and **ng-controller** in your **html/body** tags.